# How to include dependent project and splitting jar into two jars?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

It is my first time I'm writing here, so I'm hoping that I'm making everything right.

I have a Java application, let's call it A. This application depends on another project B (required project on the build path). The project structure looks as follows:

CommonFolder/Project B

```
 -- src

 -- lib

 build.xml
```

CommonFolder/subfolder/Project A

```
 -- src

 -- lib

 -- config

 build.xml
```

The build.xml in Project B works well and create a jar file in a dist folder. Now in Project A the build.xml file should first call build.xml from Project B and then it should create the jar file. Somehow this does not work. If I just copy the jar file from Project B into the lib folder of Project A it works but I don't want to do this manually.

My second problem is that the final jar file of project A will be pretty big because there are a lot of libraries in the lib folder. I would like to split the jar file into two files: libraries.jar (also containing the dependency from project B) and application.jar. When application.jar is started it should use libraries.jar (both jars in the same folder). The benefit is that I only have to upload application.jar which is much smaller (if I don't change the libraries).

How can this be done?

I'm looking forward for the answer.

Here are both build.xml files.

ProjectB

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>  
<project default="complete build" name="Create runnable jar file">  
    <property name="src.dir" location="src" />  
    <property name="lib.dir" location="lib" />  
    <property name="build.dir" location="bin" />  
    <property name="dist.dir" location="dist" />  
    <property name="build.sysclasspath" value="last" />  

    <path id="project-classpath">  
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="*.jar" />  
    </path>  

    <target name="remove release">  
        <delete dir="${dist.dir}" />  
    </target>  

    <target name="clean build">  
        <delete dir="${build.dir}" />  
    </target>  

    <target name="compile" depends="clean build">  
        <mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />  
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}" debug="on" target="1.8" source="1.8">  
            <classpath refid="project-classpath" />  
            <compilerarg value="-Xlint:none" />  
        </javac>  
    </target>  

    <target name="build jar" depends="remove release, compile">  
        <mkdir dir="${dist.dir}" />  
        <jar destfile="${dist.dir}/projectA.jar">  
            <fileset dir="${build.dir}" />  
            <zipgroupfileset dir="lib" excludes="META-INF/**" includes="*.jar"/>  
        </jar>  
        <antcall target="clean build" />  
    </target>  

    <target name="complete build" depends="build jar, clean build" />  
</project>
```

Project A

```
<path id="project-classpath">  
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="*.jar" />  
</path>  

<target name="remove release">  
    <delete dir="${dist.dir}" />  
</target>  

<target name="clean build">  
    <delete dir="${build.dir}" />  
</target>  

<target name="clean docs">  
    <delete dir="${docs.dir}" />  
</target>  

<target name="build-deps">  
    <ant antfile="../../ProjectB/build.xml" target="complete build"/>  
</target>  

<target name="compile" depends="clean build, build-deps">  
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />  
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}" debug="on" target="1.8" source="1.8">  
        <classpath refid="project-classpath" />  
        <compilerarg value="-Xlint:none" />  
    </javac>  
</target>  

<target name="docs" depends="clean docs, compile">  
    <mkdir dir="${docs.dir}" />  
    <javadoc packagenames="src" sourcepath="${src.dir}" destdir="${docs.dir}">  
        <fileset dir="${src.dir}">  
            <include name="**" />  
        </fileset>  
    </javadoc>  
</target>  

<target name="build jar" depends="remove release, compile">  
    <mkdir dir="${dist.dir}" />  
    <jar destfile="${dist.dir}/ProjectA.jar">  
        <manifest>  
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="something.main.Main" />  
            <attribute name="Class-Path" value="." />  
        </manifest>  

        <fileset dir="${build.dir}" />  
        <zipfileset dir="config" />  
        <zipgroupfileset dir="lib" excludes="META-INF/**" includes="*.jar"/>  
    </jar>  
    <antcall target="clean build" />  
</target>  

<target name="complete build" depends="docs, build jar, clean build" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following answer describes how to use Apache ivy to handle and manage multi-module project builds that have interdependencies:

- [How to import properties and targets from ant build file properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25114699/how-to-import-properties-and-targets-from-ant-build-file-properly/25116954#25116954)

It demonstrates the following:

- Each module can be built independently using cached files
- Module build order is determined using the ivy [buildlist](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/buildlist.html) task
- The ivy [buildnumber](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/buildnumber.html) task is used to auto generate the release numbers
- The ANT [manifestclasspath](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/manifestclasspath.html) task can be used to create an executable jar with the list of dependent jars.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks a lot for the useful hint.